# Grouping data into buckets - SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, bucket

I'm trying to get SQL to group some continuous data into two buckets, but it raises me an "aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause" error. How can I circumvent that ?

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN AVG(amount) BETWEEN 0 AND 100000 THEN "Group 1"
WHEN AVG(amount) > 100000 THEN "Group 2" END) AS Bucket
, AVG(amount)
FROM DB
GROUP BY bucket
```

Comment: Wrap query in outer `SELECT` query.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
(CASE amount BETWEEN 0 AND 100000 THEN "Group 1"
WHEN amount > 100000 THEN "Group 2" END) AS Bucket
, AVG(amount)
FROM DB
GROUP BY bucket
```

Comment: It only yields me the second bucket (even though I know the first one contains values)

Comment: If `amount` contains a value between 0 and 100000, then you should see a "Group 1" bucket. Maybe you can try to setup something at https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?

Comment: found the problem, my "amount' data was in string format !

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT
CASE when amount BETWEEN 0 AND 100000 THEN 'Group 1'
WHEN amount > 100000 THEN 'Group 2' END AS Bucket
, AVG(amount)
FROM DB
GROUP BY CASE when amount BETWEEN 0 AND 100000 THEN 'Group 1'
WHEN amount > 100000 THEN 'Group 2' END
```

Comment: It only yields me the second bucket (even though I know the first one contains values)

Comment: @JohannSchwaller share sample data and expected output in question

Comment: found the problem, my "amount' data was in string format !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a group by since you are dealing only with AVG.

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN AVG(amount) BETWEEN 0 AND 100000 THEN "Group 1"
WHEN AVG(amount) > 100000 THEN "Group 2" END) AS Bucket
, AVG(amount)
FROM DB
```